# Infinite loop in protocol confirmed enum variable

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7

In Xcode7.0 GM Seed, I tried this code.

```
import UIKit

protocol P {
    var n: String { get }
}

enum E: Int, P {
    case A = 0
    case B = 1
    var n: String {
        return "aa"
    }
}

class C {
    var v1: String {
        print("-- 2 --")
        return v2.n
    }

    var v2: P! {
        didSet {
            print("-- 1 --")
            print(v1)
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let c = C()
        c.v2 = E(rawValue: 0)
    }
}
```

expect

```
-- 1 --
-- 2 --
aa
```

but the result is,

```
-- 1 --
-- 2 --
-- 1 --
-- 2 --
-- 1 --
-- 2 --
...
```

and crash!

When I call v2.n, v2.didSet is also getting called. 
So infinite loop happen.

This happens only in Xcode7(Swift2) iOS8,9.
I tried the same code in Xcode6.4, but it did not enter the infinite loop.

Is this a possible bug in Swift2?

Comment: I think it is a bug.  Raise it with Apple.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a bug since this only occurs in combination with protocols.

Protocols have to support both reference types and value types. So they may have some weird behaviors when to call set and get. But in this case if you replace the protocol type with a class or struct none of them have this effects such that the setter is called even though only the getter is accessed. In conclusion, a protocol doesn't have to have this behavior in order to work with both types.